# select and set column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple table contains few columns: `Id, Name, Profit, IsBusy`. `IsBusy` is `BIT` value.
I need to create a sql script will select all not busy entries (IsBusy is 0) and the same time sets this flag to 1. So another serial or parallel queries will not get this entry becouse the flag is 1.
May be exists some technics to release my task? Thanks.

Comment: you either `SELECT` or `UPDATE` the value, not both at the same time

Comment: I need first select and then update. But I need somehow to block the table i think. How to resolve multitheaded acces in my task?

Comment: So, do you need a select of the updated records?

Comment: First I need to select all 'non busy' entries. Then sets them to 'busy'. But what will heppen if two clients same times will select whe same 'non busy' entries.

Comment: As shown in the answer from alas, you can use an `OUTPUT` clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. `Id` values.  `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both before and after values in the case of `UPDATE`.  A tool well worth having in your pocket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your requirement to stop users accessing data when you are working with some specific rows, should be handled with TRANSACTIONS and ISOLATION LEVEL.

You should look into the most strictest isolation level i.e SERIALIZABLE.

You should change the transaction isolation level to SERIALIZABLE and then select rows and it will obtain exclusive locks on the rows locking out any other users who may also want to read the same rows.

You can change the transaction isolation level to SERIALIZABLE with the following command.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
```

*Important Note*

Mind you this may very well result in extensive blocking of users and you may endup with many unhappy end-users whose screen keep freezing :) .

Also you have mentioned that you want to select rows and then update.

Update statement obtains UPDATE LOCK on rows under default isolation level (Read Uncommitted) If you are updating a row users will not be able to access the row until your update is committed or rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

Would something like the following work for you?

```
update X
set IsBusy = 1
output inserted.Id, inserted.Name
where IsBusy = 0
```

Comment: Basically the above query will return the updated records of the update operation.